# English grammar linkers and connectors

Tags: grammar

A student of mine has asked - Is "than ever before" a linker or a connector? I don't think it's either.

Comment: As far as I know, neither _linker_ nor _connector_ is an established term in linguistics, so you'll need to explain the terms, or at least cite a source that defines them. It may be easier for you to go to whatever course or textbook you learnt the terms from and see what they say about the phrase.

Comment: It's an adverbial phrase, but it doesn't serve to link or connect